React Native/Expo Go app fails to make a request to my Node/Express API
The context is that I was using my current API with my React project on the web, but it turned out we needed a mobile application instead and I started developing one with react-native and expo go, I researched and found out I can use my Node/Express app without modifying it at all inside the mobile app.
this is my node/express server's index.js:
const express = require("express");
const https = require("https");
const cors = require("cors");
const { Server } = require("socket.io");
const connectDB = require("./utils/database");
const orderRoutes = require("./routes/orderRoutes");
const inventoryRoutes = require("./routes/inventoryRoutes");

const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());

connectDB();

app.use("/orders", orderRoutes);
app.use("/inventory", inventoryRoutes);

const server = https.createServer(app);
const io = new Server(server, {
  cors: {
    origin: "*",
    methods: ["GET", "POST"],
  },
});

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  console.log("New client connected");

  socket.on("disconnect", () => {
    console.log("Client disconnected");
  });
});

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("Your server is working!");
});

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
server.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server running`);
});


this is how I try to access is in my react-native project:
 useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://192.168.1.85:5000/inventory")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((json) => console.log(json))
      .catch((error) => console.error("Error fetching data:", error));
  }, []);

these are the things I've tried, but without success:

Adding proxy to the backend inside the app.json
Installing expo-build-properties and adding "usesCleartextTraffic": true
Using localhost instead of the ipv4
Trying to access it from both physical device and emulator with expo go

things to consider:

When I access the 192.168.1.85:5000/inventory in my browser from both my phone and pc, it works perfectly, so the problem comes somewhere in the expo go in my opinion
Using any deployed backend works, for example: https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1  (this excludes any possible internet connectivity issues)
When inspecting the network tab, there isn't even a request showing there, which means its not even talking to the server in any way, which again tells me its not a problem with my server.
I read all of the available info on this i could find and the most common ways to fix it, I have already tried. The only one I havet tried and I saw its highly recommended is the the one where you modify a file named AndroidManifest.xml, because for me it doesn't exist.


This is all the available info I could think of, let me know if I can provide you with something else.

That maybe because when you do run your expo app with command npm start or expo start. It usually runs on 192.168.1.40:8081 and your express is running on 192.168.1.85:5000. So, you might have to start that port separately. Hope this helps.

just remove this line .then((response) =>response.json()) because the data fetched from react native is different from the data of react or browser fetched so your code should looks like this
useEffect(() => {
fetch("https://192.168.1.85:5000/inventory")
  .then((json) => console.log(json))
  .catch((error) => console.error("Error fetching data:", 
error));
}, []);

I have tried in my Expo go and it worked good .
